# Eclipse Conditional replace with regex

Tags: regex, eclipse, replace

Given the text

```
public void MyFunction(int i, String str, boolean doIt) {
    Log.i(TAG, "Enter MyFunction(int i, String str, boolean doIt)");
```

I want to make some replacements on the second line, but not the first

```
public void MyFunction(int i, String str, boolean doIt) {
    Log.i(TAG, "Enter MyFunction( i:" + i + ", str:" + str ", doIt:" + doIt + ")");
```

So far using the following regex I manage to get these results:

find "`\w+\s+(\w+)([,\)])`"
replace with "`$1:" + $1 + "$2`"

```
public void MyFunction(i:" + i + ", str:" + str ", doIt:" + doIt + ") ") {
    Log.i(TAG, "Enter MyFunction( i:" + i + ", str:" + str ", doIt:" + doIt + ") ");
```

Is there any way to force the replace to be executed only on the **Log.i** lines?

**EDIT:**
I tried the following regex
"`Log\.i\(.*?\((\s*(\w+\s+(\w+)([,\)]))+`"
but $1,$2,$3 only contains the last match (the last argument: doIt)

> $1=boolean doIt)
>   $2=doIt
>   $3=)

when there should be 3 sets of $1,$2,$3, one for each argument.
If you know how to retrieve multiple matches, that would also make for a solution

Comment: Only match lines that start with `Log.i`...

Comment: I think you mean Java, the Eclipse IDE has little to do with your problem.

Comment: @MattBall You can notice the regex I presented does 3 matches, not one. If I put the Log.i as part of the regex only the first, or last, argument will match. :::: If you have a solution, please post it and I'll try it.

Comment: @Junuxx I actually mean the Eclipse editor, with its search end replace function for any text file :::: Yes in my case is Java code, but is not relevant to the question , it could be for C#, C++, etc.

Comment: @ilomambo: Ah I see, that wasn't very clear from the question. I thought your program dealt with strings that looked like code.

Comment: The second regex `Log\.i(\s*(\w+\s+(\w+)([,\)]))+` is not valid - there's an unclosed `)`.

Comment: @MattBall Right, I wrote it from memory since I tried it a few hours ago, I corrected it now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I caved,

I used this little perl to do the job:

```
next unless /Log\.i/;
s/TAG,/TAGG/;
s/(final\s+)?[^ \(]+\s+(\w+)([,\)])/$2:\" \+ $2 \+ \"$3/g;
s/TAGG/TAG,/;
```

with the command line:

```
perl -pi <scriptname> <file>
```

If someone still wants to contribute some, I understand I could have run perl as Eclipse external tool to process the java files. How do I do that?

**UPDATE:**

I wrote a post on how to use external perl to run the script from within Eclipse IDE
[see the post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10960339/android-eclipse-use-external-tools-to-run-a-script-on-the-code/10960605#10960605)